# Using probabilities on churn and death

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, churn

I've been assigned with 2 models that forecast probabilities of **death** and **churn** for some clients. For every client, a 1 is assigned if the person left the company, or if he-she died, thus the task is to classify each person into those 2 categories given variables like gender, age, income an so on.
The models are used to estimate the probabilities for 30 periods of time using other models that forecast inputs like income, savings, etc., and on each period a "gross" Flow (inflows - outflows) is obtained. After that, the team that took the project before me calculated the net flow as:

```
NetFlow=(1-D)(1-C)GrossFlow
```

where T and C are the probabilities of dying or leaving, for each period of time.

Because a person that left or died cannot die or leave again the next period (of course), it makes sense to consider conditional probabilities, that is, obtaining the probabilities of dying/leaving given that the client didn't leave or die in the past.

My questions are 2:

- If my probabilities give the odds of dying/leaving on a specific period, how should I approach probabilities for the case that didn't die/leave in the past: using multiplication of probabilities (prob. of staying is ($1-P.leaving_{t=1}$)*($1-P.leaving_{t=2}$) or using sum of probabilites (e.g. $P[x_t<2]$ would mean the probability of dying before t=2)
- How can I take into consideration, inside the model, the fact that someone died/left cannot keep on dying/leaving. This is specially true because for some cases, the company may keep some money from a dead client for a period of time. Can I obtain conditional probabilities form a model?

Thanks in advance!

Also, I didn't want to provide some fake data, because it would just be numbers ordered by period, although I believe that some example could be quite illustrative.